# Power BI ARIMA Forecasting

Tags: r, powerbi, forecasting, powerbi-embedded

I just started using the power BI ARIMA forecast. How do you extract the forecasted values? Using the ARIMA visualization you can't seem to click on the data/drill "see records" or "see data" button.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/R-Script-Showcase/ARIMA-forecasting/m-p/124237), they're saying it is not supported right now.